# How to get TypeScript with VS 2013 for Windows Desktop

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Desktop and I tried to install TypeScript plugin. It installed successfully, then I opened Visual Studio, but I didn't see it anywhere, even under the Visual Basic or Visual C# Templates.

What should I do to make it work ?

Comment: You want Visual Studio for *Web* , not *Desktop*.

Comment: Ok, I will install VS for Web

Comment: Why not just install Visual Studio 2013 Community?